# Strange LIKE button error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, button, facebook-like

For some reason a LIKE button that has been working fine for a couple months stopped working on the 13th. When clicked it displays a red Error and when you click that it says to check the url with the linter and fix any errors. The problem is that the url linter does not show any errors to fix, so we have no idea why the like buttons on these pages in particular have stopped working. Even if I make a copy of the page with a different page name it still gives the error. Other pages on the site can still be liked with no errors.

Can someone run this URL through the linter and tell me what might be wrong with the tags on the page that would cause LIKE to suddenly fail when it worked fine up to the 13th?

Note this is a copy of the pages giving the error as we removed the like button from the live pages as visitors were annoyed with the error.

http://apps.facebook.com/tobqcontest/viewproject.cfm?entry_id=253

Thanks for any advice on why all LIKE buttons for these pages fail with a generic error